# Is this space Pathconnected?

Tags: general-topology

Is the infinite unions of  $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\}$ path connected.

Are they actually equal to the space $[0,1)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is path-connected and equal to $[0,1)$.

Comment: Horrible Space! Thanks!

Comment: @rk101 I'm sorry : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just $[0,1)$, as

$$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1) = (0,1)$$

Comment: Can you think of any spaces that are connected but not path connected? Apart form the topologists sine curve?

Comment: @rk101: That's a totally new question. Ask it separately if you want to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is true that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\} \subseteq [0,1)$.

What about the other direction? Pick any $x \in (0,1)$ (we already know that $0$ is contained in the left-hand side). By the Archimedean Property, there is $N$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{N} < x$. Thus, $x \in (\frac{1}{N}, 1)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\} \supseteq [0,1)$, and so the two sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

to prove that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\}=[0,1)$ we just prove the double inclusions:

If $X\in\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)$ then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $X\in (\frac{1}{n},1)$ then $X\in [0,1)$ because $0<\frac{1}{n}\leq 1$ if $X=0$ then $X\in [0,1)$.

If $X\in [0,1)$ and $X\neq 0$ then by the property of infinimum, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $X\in (\frac{1}{n},1)$ then $X\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)$ and if $X=0$ then $X\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\}$.

we conclude that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n},1)  \cup\{{0}\}=[0,1)$, and for sure $[0,1)$ is path connected.